# Find a determinant of a matrix $M_{(n)x(n)}$ depending on the $x,y,n \in \mathbb R$

Tags: linear-algebra

I had a matrix which I I transformed to zero as many matrix elements as possible and in this time I have: $$y^{n} \cdot det \begin{vmatrix} 
\frac{x}{y}+1 & 1 & ... &     &  & 1\\
\frac{-x}{y} &  \frac{x}{y}  &     &     &  & 0 \\
. &  0  & \frac{x}{y} &  0  &  ...   & .  \\
. &  .  & ... &    &     &  . \\
. & . &     &    &     & .  \\
\frac{-x}{y} & 0  & ... &    &     &\frac{x}{y}  \\
 \end{vmatrix}
$$ Unfortunately I don't know what can I do to find a sollution at this moment. Can you help me with some tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Assumed that your calculations so far are correct,) you're almost there.

Just add the second, third, ... $n$th columns to the first column, so that your matrix will become an upper triangle matrix and its determinant is the product of the diagonal elements.

Comment: In my previous transformations, I used row operations. Can I now transform columns?

Comment: Row transformations retain the set of roots of system corresponding to the matrix, column transformations don't. However  iff your aim is just calculating the determinant you can mix row and column transformations.

Comment: Using $\det(A^T) =\det A$, we see that the column operations change the determinant the same way as the row operations.